# How to scrape data generated dynamically on selecting drop down menus one after other using Beautifulsoup and Selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape data from following website :
http://b2b.godrejinterio.com/GodrejInterio/dealer.aspx?id=29&menuid=2458&business=2

Here, data is dynamically generated on the same page itself without any change in URL.
Everytime you option from 1st dropdown menu, then only 2nd dropdown becomes active and allows you to select option from 2nd dropdown and so on for 3rd & 4th dropdown menu.

After selection of all the dropdown menus, you have to click on search button then only data gets generated on the same page.

I need to scrape data for all possible selections in one go. Below is the code which i tried but it wont work as desired. I am using python and tools as beautifulsoup & selenium. Help me with this!!

Mike67, I have used your suggestion and improved code, but still I am unable to iterate within option and save code to dataframe. Help me with this !!
Code :

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--incognito')
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/Downloads/chromedriver")

rec=[]

driver.get("http://b2b.godrejinterio.com/GodrejInterio/dealer.aspx?id=29&menuid=2458&business=2")
# wait=WebDriverWait(driver,10)

time.sleep(2)
s1 = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ucInterioDealerLocatorNewRight_ddlRange"))
s1.select_by_value("Institutional Furniture")
# print(s1.options[0].text)

time.sleep(2)
# wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_element_located((By.ID,"ucInterioDealerLocatorNewRight_ddlRange")))
s22 = driver.find_element_by_id("ucInterioDealerLocatorNewRight_ddlSubRange")
s2 = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ucInterioDealerLocatorNewRight_ddlSubRange"))
all_options1 = s22.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")
for option1 in all_options1:
    option1=option1.get_attribute("value")
    print(option1)
    if(option1=='0'):
        continue
    else:
        s2.select_by_value(option1)

        time.sleep(10)
        # wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_element_located((By.ID,"ucInterioDealerLocatorNewRight_ddlSubRange")))
        s33 = driver.find_element_by_id("ucInterioDealerLocatorNewRight_ddlState")
        s3 = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ucInterioDealerLocatorNewRight_ddlState"))
        all_options2 = s33.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")
        for option2 in all_options2:
            option2=option2.get_attribute("value")
            print(option2)
            s3.select_by_value(option2)
            # print(s3.options[1].text)

            time.sleep(10)
            # wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.ID,"ucInterioDealerLocatorNewRight_ddlState")))
            s44 = driver.find_element_by_id("ucInterioDealerLocatorNewRight_ddlCity")
            s4 = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ucInterioDealerLocatorNewRight_ddlCity"))
            all_options3 = s44.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")
            for option3 in all_options3:
                option3=option3.get_attribute("value")
                print(option3)
                if(option3=='0'):
                    continue
                else:
                    s4.select_by_value(option3)
                    # print(s4.options[1].text)

                    time.sleep(10)
                    # wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.ID,"ucInterioDealerLocatorNewRight_ddlCity")))
                    s55 = driver.find_element_by_id("ucInterioDealerLocatorNewRight_ddlArea")
                    s5 = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ucInterioDealerLocatorNewRight_ddlArea"))
                    all_options4 = s55.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")
                    for option4 in all_options4:
                        option4=option4.get_attribute("value")
                        print(option4)
                        if(option4=='0'):
                            continue
                        else:
                            s5.select_by_value(option4)
                            # print(s4.options[1].text)

                            time.sleep(10)
                            s6=driver.find_element_by_id("ucInterioDealerLocatorNewRight_imgBtnSearch").click()
                            # for i in s6.find_all('div')
                            # print(type(s6))
                            # print(s4.content)

                            time.sleep(10)
                            # wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME,"dealer_search_maindiv")))
                            # r1 = driver.find_element_by_class_name("dealer_search_maindiv")
                            html=driver.page_source
                            # print(html)
                            soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html5lib')
                            try:
                                cl=soup.find('div',attrs={'class':'dealer_search_maindiv'})
                                for i in range(0,10):
                                    i=str(i)
                                    idd= f"ucInterioDealerLocatorNewRight_dlDealer_ctl0{i}_tblDealer"
                                    kwargs={'id': 'idd' }
                                    kwargs['id'] = idd
                                    d1=cl.find('table', kwargs)
                                    data=";"
                                    d2 = d1.find('table')
                                    for d3 in d2.find_all('tr'):
                                        j=d3.find('td').text
                                        print(j)
                                        data = data + j + ';'
                                    print(data)
                                    rec.append(data)
                            except:
                                print("no record for this selection")
                                continue
    print("state done")
print("all subrange completed")
print(len(rec))
df=pd.DataFrame({'Record':rec})
driver.close()
```

Comment: Where are you exactly stuck? Which line? Do you see any error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `time.sleep` in between each dropdown change, the page works:

```
driver.get("http://b2b.godrejinterio.com/GodrejInterio/dealer.aspx?id=29&menuid=2458&business=2")

time.sleep(2)
s1 = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ucInterioDealerLocatorNewRight_ddlRange"))
s1.select_by_value("Institutional Furniture")
print(s1.options[0].text)

time.sleep(2)
s2 = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ucInterioDealerLocatorNewRight_ddlSubRange"))
s2.select_by_value("Desking")

time.sleep(2)
s3 = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ucInterioDealerLocatorNewRight_ddlState"))
s3.select_by_value("Delhi")
print(s3.options[0].text)

driver.find_element_by_id("ucInterioDealerLocatorNewRight_imgBtnSearch").click()
```

Comment: Use driver.implicitly_wait() instead of sleep.